# Options for firewall logging in AWS on EC2 instances?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, amazon-ec2, redhat, amazon-web-services

We are looking to implement a logger for our firewall, in the cloud, to log attempted requests and general traffic to and from the server. For general traffic to and from the server the AWS firewall will pass us that traffic and we can log it using a wide range of current tools. This will not show us any denied requests to the server from the AWS firewall. I don't want to use an agent based firewall, but understand if I must. We mainly are a windows server environment. We do on occasion have a few red hat Linux servers. That is around 5% of our total infrastructure. So what is the easiest and cost effective solution to log denied firewall attempts in AWS enviroment?

Comment: Windows? Linux? ObscureOS 13.37?

Comment: Windows mainly. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 1):

As far as the AWS firewall (SecurityGroup) you wont be able to get any logging from that. For specific instances I'm sure a tech could work with you from amazon assuming you have Premium Support. If you need to log attempted denied firewall attempts you'll need to have a software based firewall. There are already some options to use in AWS if you look at the marketplace you can see the prices for different software.

For example something like [Vyatta Virtual Router/Firewall/VPN](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B009I5TLOE/ref=brs_res_product_title?ie=UTF8&sr=0-44&qid=1359468693512) could work for you. I haven't used any of the software firewalls in the cloud as I have no need to log failed attempts.

Comment: I saw that, and looked into it. It looks like an option for a firewall on the perimeter, not per an instance. AlertLogic has a linux/windows solution but it's a "soft tap". I messaged AWS support, but was sent to their sales staff.

Comment: If you don't have Premium support its unlikely they will help you will technical requests such as access to logs. I think most of the Firewall software is going to be perimeter and not per instance. Since you're using windows maybe try using the firewall that comes with windows http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc947815(v=ws.10).aspx.